# Is there a bug with 'Prefers large titles' in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, preferslargetitles

Xcode has this strange behaviour of:

1. NOT changing the root view controller's title bar to a large title in the storyboard
2. Changing the title bar's background color to white

Does anyone has the same strange experience or am I doing something wrong?

[Behaviour when changing "Prefers large titles"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2Gfo.gif)

[While the app is running.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLSTr.gif)

Comment: Same. Did you ever find a solution for this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I switched back to the normal centered title.